# How did the theories of Lavoisier, Davy, Arrhenius then Bronsted & Lowry come about?

Tags: discoveries, chemistry

What scientific experimentations, methods of thinking, ideas and so forth necessitate each individual definition of their acids / bases?

Comment: Title and contents have nothing to do with each other!

Comment: Hi, welcome to hsm. Under acid–base reaction Wikipedia lists each of the theories and gives some historical details. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid%E2%80%93base_reaction#Historic_development Let us know what your interest is more specifically because currently the question is too broad for a good answer.